# Error calling 'npm install' with Meteor via Demeteorizer

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteorite

I'm currently getting this error when trying to call 'npm install' on the generated file by demeteorizer.

```
npm WARN package.json gw2events@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json progress@0.0.5 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json uglify-js@2.2.5 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json uglify-js@2.2.5 'repositories' (plural) Not supported.
npm WARN package.json Please pick one as the 'repository' field
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/kexec/0.1.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/kexec/0.1.1
npm WARN package.json kexec@0.1.1 homepage field must be a string url. Deleted.

> kexec@0.1.1 install /Users/athiwat/Development/gw2events/.demeteorized/node_modules/kexec
> node-gyp configure build

gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.12/node-v0.10.12.tar.gz
gyp http 200 http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.12/node-v0.10.12.tar.gz
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kexec/src/kexec.o
In file included from ../src/kexec.cc:2:
In file included from /Users/athiwat/.node-gyp/0.10.12/deps/v8/include/v8.h:41:
/Users/athiwat/.node-gyp/0.10.12/deps/v8/include/v8stdint.h:34:10: fatal error: 
      'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/kexec/src/kexec.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/athiwat/Development/gw2events/.demeteorized/node_modules/kexec
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.12
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I tried searching around. I have no clue right now.

Comment: Can you please paste the contents of the package.json file that Demeteorizer created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an xCode problem on the newest Mac OSX Marvicks.
You need to install the developer preview of xCode 5 to get the PATH to work. (Without any further work of course).